# Listings "cannot load requested language"

Tags: listings

If my understanding that it is possible to specify the programming language for the listings globally as well as on the listing by listing basis is correct, than the following should work:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstloadlanguages{SQL,Basic} %Listings manual, pp. 11, 13
\lstset{
     frameround=fttt
    ,language=SQL
    ,numbers=left
    ,breaklines=true
    ,showstringspaces=false
    ,basicstyle=\small
}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Basic,label={lst:ssrscurmon}]
=MonthName(DatePart(DateInterval.Month, Today()))
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

But it instead throws

```
Package Listings Error: Couldn't load requested language \lstloadlanguages{SQL,Basic}
```

How can I specify Basic for some listings in the document, where the majority are in SQL?

Comment: Seems that `Basic` is missing in the list of available languages for some reason.  Also, I recommend you move the `\lstloadlanguages` and the `\lstset{ to the preamble _before_ `\begin{document}`.

Comment: P. 4 of the Listings user guide instructs to put the `\lstset` inside the document body. Why do you recommend putting it in the preamble?

Comment: Yes, there is an _example_ of how one _can_ use `lstset` _after_ `\begin{document}`. My recommendation was more about `\lstloadlanguages` as I can not see any reason to load that in the main documents. Even `lstset`, IMHO, should be used _only_ for document wide settings and `style=` settings be used for customization, although it is possible to use `lstset` to change the settings mid-document.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be considered a bug in `listings`; in [`lstdvrs.dtx`](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/listings/lstdrvrs.dtx), more specifically.

The [`lstdvrs.dtx`](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/listings/lstdrvrs.dtx) file is where all `listings` *languages* and *dialects* are defined. In particular, a language called `Basic` (together with only one dialect, `Visual`) is defined there.

The problem is that, even though the `Basic` language comes with only one dialect (`Visual`), the *default dialect* for Basic is defined nowhere in `lstdvrs.dtx`. Therefore, if you simply specify

```
language=Basic
```

`listings` has no clue which language you're referring to! The same problem arises, for the same reason, if you try to load the `Assembler` language without also specifying a dialect.

To fix the problem, you have two options:

1. Whenever you want to use Basic, specify its only dialect (`Visual`) also:

   ```
   language={[Visual]Basic}
   ```
2. Fix that bug in `listings` yourself by defining the default dialect for `Basic`:

   ```
   \lstset{defaultdialect=[Visual]Basic}
   ```

   ([As Peter notes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212069/listings-cannot-load-requested-language/212080#comment496245_212069), this should preferably be done in your preamble. You should endeavour to separate style from content; the former should go in the preamble, whereas the latter should go in the body of your document.)

   Then you should be able to use the `Basic` language without mishap. No need to use `\lstloadlanguages` at all (although, as [pointed out by Peter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212069/listings-cannot-load-requested-language/212080#comment496315_212080), you may still want to load the languages you use right after loading the `listings` package, for efficiency reasons; see the note at the bottom of section 2.2 in the documentation).

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{book}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    defaultdialect=[Visual]Basic
    ,frameround=fttt
    ,language=SQL
    ,numbers=left
    ,breaklines=true
    ,showstringspaces=false
    ,basicstyle=\small
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Basic,label={lst:ssrscurmon}]
=MonthName(DatePart(DateInterval.Month, Today()))
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that when `\lstloadlanguages` is used, compilation time is much shorter. Of course my machine could be acting up, but that is my impression.

Comment: @ajeh: Yep, the documentation (P. 11) states that it is much faster to load several languages with one command rather than each language being loaded on demand.

Comment: @PeterGrill I didn't know anything about that. Feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: @Jubobs: I didn't either (just discovered it today while trying to research this question). I started to edit your answer, but then realized that you don't actually use `\lstloadlanguages` in your answer, so not sure it makes sense to add that comment.

Comment: @PeterGrill Ok, fair enough. I'll read more about it and see if I should mention it somewhere later. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As you can see on Table 1 (page 13) of the `listings` documentation, only Visual Basic is supported; this can also be seen in the file `lstlang1.sty`, where you find the definition

```
\lst@definelanguage[Visual]{Basic}
  {
  ...
  }
```

You need the to load `[Visual](Basic)`; the complete code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstloadlanguages{SQL,[Visual]Basic} %Listings manual, pp. 11, 13
\lstset{
     frameround=fttt
    ,language=SQL
    ,numbers=left
    ,breaklines=true
    ,showstringspaces=false
    ,basicstyle=\small
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language={[Visual]Basic},label={lst:ssrscurmon}]
=MonthName(DatePart(DateInterval.Month, Today()))
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: The line `\lst@definelanguage[Visual]{Basic}` doesn't itself indicate that `Basic` can only be used in conjunction with `Visual`. Rather, it's the fact that no default dialect is defined for the `Basic` language.

Comment: Lack of underline under Visual in the table on p. 13 should have been a hint to me, but I missed it.