# Listings “cannot load requested language” after newly-defined dialect

Tags: listings

[Note that this is *not* a duplicate of [ajeh's question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212069/listings-cannot-load-requested-language)]

I have defined a new XSLT2 dialect of XML for the listings package which includes some extra keywords beyond XSLT, but I can't get it to recognise this: I get the error message

```
! Package Listings Error: Couldn't load requested language.

See the Listings package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.10 \begin{lstlisting}[language=XSLT2]

! Package Listings Error: language xslt2 undefined.
```

(also weird is that it quotes xslt2 in lowercase, but that's probably a different matter).

Here is the MWE (extra keywords cut):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinelanguage[XSLT2]{XML}% copied from lstlang1.sty
  {morekeywords={xsl:for-each-group},%
   alsodigit={-},%
  }%
\lstloadlanguages{[XSLT2]XML}
\begin{document}
This is a test
\begin{lstlisting}[language=XSLT2]
<xsl:for-each-group select="db:biblioentry">
  ...
</xsl:for-each-group>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

> [edit] I am aware that I can use `[language={[XSLT2]XML}]`, but if I use the existing XSLT language I don't have to do `{[XSLT]XML}`...how do I implement it so that it works in the same way? I have tried using `\lstset{defaultdialect=[XSLT2]XML}` but it has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to define a dialect but a new language based on xml, so your syntax is wrong. It should be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinelanguage{XSLT2}[]{XML}% changed
  {morekeywords={xsl:for-each-group},%
   alsodigit={-},%
  }%
\lstloadlanguages{XSLT2}
\begin{document}
This is a test
\begin{lstlisting}[language=XSLT]
<xsl:for-each-group select="db:biblioentry">
  ...
</xsl:for-each-group>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for that...I had completely misunderstood the arguments: I thought it was the other way round...